# Save Emoticon in SQL Server database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing a web application in Asp.Net. I have a text column where user types description of product.

It is saving correctly, but If I use emoticon while typing description from mobile, It is saved as `??` in the database.

How can I save it properly and display it next time to user what he typed?

I tried following solution with no result

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

I guess It is encoding problem.

Any help?

Comment: whats datatype of table column ?

Comment: is that getting saved correctly?check data in table or just '??' in table?

Comment: Please clarify if you mean "emoticon" (using normal punctuation characters) or "emoji" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji)

Comment: Where did you see it was "saved as ??"? Through Management Studio or when you read the stored value back into the .Net code? Also please show how you store/retrieve the value.

Comment: @utility.. It is just ??

Comment: It viewed it in management studio. I am saving like this.

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                    cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = notification.Description;

Comment: A wild guess: management studio doesn't know how to show those emoji. Try and read the value back into your application - it may just work.

Comment: It is not working, reading back is showing question mark

Comment: Are you sure that UTF-8 is the correct encoding? nvarchar uses UCS-2!

Comment: I am not sure about it.

Comment: Try to use `Encoding.Unicode` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For storing texts thats not supported in Sql Server, your tables should have unichar support.

Create the columns in Table and make sure that it's data type like `nvarchar`.

Now you can store emoticons and different languages fonts as well in Sql Server Database.

```
 @icontext nvarchar(MAX)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@icontext", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

> No need to store in bytes for emoticons :)

Edit 1:

**Note :**

When dealing with Unicode string constants in SQL Server you must precede all Unicode strings with a capital letter N, as documented in the SQL Server Books Online topic "Using Unicode Data". The "N" prefix stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard, and must be uppercase. If you do not prefix a Unicode string constant with N, SQL Server will convert it to the non-Unicode code page of the current database before it uses the string.

Comment: Now it saves square block instead of smiley against :-)

Comment: Can you help me more?

Comment: so now you can save and retrieve emoticons ..right ?

Comment: Still I am unable to save and retrieve.

Comment: do you want to save this -   :)  ..sure?

Comment: I want to save emoji from iPhone and Android?

Comment: have a look here and give a try.eventhough i have not tested them..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/684717/Emoji-and-web-application

Comment: This is using MySql, I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah yeah, i have read. 
This is not for SQL Server, it is for MSSQL.